# CreateProcess() not starting process correctly

Tags: c++, winapi

Im trying to simply launch an application using the function below but it dosent seem to work properly. It will not launch my test app from the desktop but when i moved it to a sub folder in Downloads it worked fine. Im pulling the directory information from a config file and considering that i can launch the test app from a separate folder already, i doubt it has anything to do with my directory information.

```
bool StartTest(){
    char WOW_PATH[MAX_PATH];
    char WOW_PATH_FULL[MAX_PATH];
    STARTUPINFO SUI;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION PROCINFO;

    SUI.cb          = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    SUI.lpReserved  = 0;
    SUI.lpTitle     = 0;
    SUI.dwFlags     = STARTF_RUNFULLSCREEN;
    SUI.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
    SUI.cbReserved2 = 0;
    SUI.lpReserved2 = 0;

    ZeroMemory(&PROCINFO,sizeof(PROCINFO));

    ifstream File;
    File.open("config.txt");
    File.getline(WOW_PATH,MAX_PATH);
    File.close();

    strcpy(WOW_PATH_FULL,WOW_PATH);

    strcpy(WOW_PATH_FULL,"\Test.exe");

    if(!CreateProcess(WOW_PATH_FULL,0,0,0,false,0,0,WOW_PATH,&SUI,&PROCINFO))
        return 0;

    CloseHandle(PROCINFO.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(PROCINFO.hThread);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can show us a log of what the precise value of `WOW_PATH_FULL` is for both a  working and a failure example.  Also, what does `GetLastError()` say?

Comment: No `GetLastError` info?  Try to find out what's wrong before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the following lines needs to have the backslash escaped.  And the second call needs to be strcat, not strcpy.

```
strcpy(WOW_PATH_FULL,WOW_PATH);
strcpy(WOW_PATH_FULL,"\Test.exe");
```

Here's the fix:

```
strcpy(WOW_PATH_FULL,WOW_PATH);
strcat(WOW_PATH_FULL,"\\Test.exe");
```

Comment: Also, check out the Win32 helper function, PathAppend or one of it's derivates. It automatically takes care of the backslash for you. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Or just use '/' - Windows is perfectly fine with that as a path separator.

Comment: Also - I wonder why when using the "sub folder in Downloads" it worked?